# How can I delete a mutex and semaphore in win32 api?

Tags: c, winapi, mutex, semaphore

I'm currently programming in C with win32 API.
I would like to know how can I permanently delete or cancel a mutex and semaphore.
How can I do that, I haven't found anything about it in MSDN till now.
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) all handles that are opened to that mutex / semaphore.

If you don't own some of them, you can not.

Answer (score 4):

You should use CloseHandle to close the mutex or semaphore.

Please read:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724211(v=vs.85).aspx
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682411(v=vs.85).aspx